# JSONObject text format error in executing http client through Java

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I have this code where I am executing a `http client` to get a response.

```
public String exmp(StringBuilder sql, String table){
    authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(target, basicAuth);

    localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);
    String postJsonstr=null;
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(API_URL);

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("{");
        str.append("\"format\":\"csv\",");
        str.append("\"version\":\"1.0\",");
        str.append("\"name\":\""+table+"\",");
        str.append("\"encrypted\":\"none\",");
        str.append("\"queries\":[{");
        str.append("\"name\":\""+table+"\",");
        str.append("\"query\":\"" + sql + "\",");
        str.append("\"type\":\"export\"");
        str.append("}]");
        str.append("}");

        httpPost.addHeader("accept", jsonContentType);
        StringEntity posEnt = new StringEntity(str.toString().trim());
        posEnt.setContentType(jsonContentType);
        httpPost.setEntity(posEnt);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpPost, localContext);}
```

When I am executing this code I am getting error as : `org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`.

I tried to do `System.out.println((int)sb.toString().trim().charAt(0));` to see what the first character is coming as and it is `123` which according to some posts is correct code for '{'.

In the above code `httpclient` is a global variable of the class (`static CloseableHttpClient httpclient;`) and is initialized in a function which is called before the above function from `main` using httpclient = `HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentials).build();`.

I am unable to understand why this error is coming when I have `{` at the first character.

**UPDATED CODE:** This is my updated code with the use of `JSONObject`. I still get the same error

```
public String exmp(StringBuilder sql, String table){
        authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(target, basicAuth);

        localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);
        String postJsonstr=null;
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(API_URL);

            JSONObject sbjson = new JSONObject();
            sbjson.put("format", "csv");
            sbjson.put("version", "1.0");
            sbjson.put("name", table);
            sbjson.put("encrypted", "none");

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
            item.put("name", table);
            item.put("query", sql);
            item.put("type", "export");
            array.put(item);

            sbjson.put("queries", array);

            httpPost.addHeader("accept", jsonContentType);
            StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(sbjson.toString());
            posEnt.setContentType(jsonContentType);
            httpPost.setEntity(posEnt);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpPost, localContext);}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON API to create the JSON, rather than building it by hand?

Comment: @JonSkeet How can I create the JSON of above structure through JSON API? Can you provide me example?

Comment: You'd create a JSONObject (or whatever the equivalent is in whichever API you use), then set the `format` property to `"csv"`, the `version` property to `"1.0"` etc. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @JonSkeet If I create a JSONObject then how will I set entity in `httpPost.setEntity(posEnt);` which expects a `StringEntity` object and `StringEntity` does not take JSONObject type and only string type. Also, no I haven't tried the JSON API and thats why was asking if you could provide me an example

Comment: So convert the JSONObject to a String... the point is that then you don't need to worry about handling all the escaping etc yourself. And you should *try* this with a JSON API yourself before asking for help - it's important to be able to research different techniques, even if *sometimes* you get stuck. (Hint: I strongly suspect you can find *some* examples of posting JSON to a web service using HttpClient and a JSON API...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I added `JSONObject sbJSON = new JSONObject(sb.toString());` and then `StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(sbJSON.toString());` but get same error again.

Comment: Humbug, I'm sure I started writing a reply, but I can't find it now. The point of using a JSON API is to avoid having all that string escaping. There's no point in building it all up manually and *then* creating a `JSONObject`. Where *exactly* are you getting the exception? Do you control the server, so can log what that's receiving?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated the code above in update section. I am now using `JSONObject` and not string but I still get same error. Also, no server is not under my control so I do not know what it is receiving at its end

Comment: Right, that's much better. Now, what is `jsonContentType`? Have you verified (e.g. with Wireshark) what the request looks like? Do you have any *working* requests to compare this with, e.g. from another client?

Comment: @JonSkeet `jsonContentType` is defined globally with `final String jsonContentType = "application/json";`. Since I am new to this so I have no idea of what and how to use different tools and clients.The supposed format of JSON based on the document should be : `{
"format" : "csv",
"version" : "1.0",
"name" : "temp",
"encrypted" : "none",
  "queries"  : [ {
    "name" : "temp",
    "query" : "select * from temp",
    "type" : "export"
  }]
}`

Comment: Right, well I suggest you investigate what working clients there are - and definitely learn about Wireshark, so you can see what the request looks like (assuming you can use HTTP instead of HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("{\"format \":\"csv \""
            + ",\"version \":\"1.0 \""
            + ",\"name \":\"%s\""
            + ",\"encrypted \":\"none \""
            + ",\"queries \":[{\"name \":\"%s\"\""
                           + ",\"query\":\"%s\""
                           + ",\"type\":\"export\"}]}",
              table, table, sql);
```

Comment: whats the difference between `StringBuilder` that I have in my code and `String.format()` version that you have posted? I have also tried `JSONObject` version (code in updated section of post) but I still the same error.

Comment: You can take the JSON string and check where is the problem. I can recommend [jsonviewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) for formatting and validation online.